# less-plugin-autoprefix plugin with Gulp showing error

Tags: less, gulp, autoprefixer

The `less-plugin-autoprefixer` plugin [README](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix/blob/master/README.md) says that, to use the plugin, you include this in your gulpfile.js:

```
var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefixPlugin = new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});
less.render(lessString, { plugins: [autoprefixPlugin] })
  .then(
```

Do they want me to put an open ended callback function here? I'm confused. I tried including just the first part:

```
var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
        autoprefixPlugin = new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});
```

and then called the plugin like this:

```
gulp.task('less', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app.less')
        .pipe(less({
            includePaths: ['less'],
            plugins: [autoprefixPlugin] //***//
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin({keepSpecialComments: 0}))
        .pipe(rename('app.full.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../server/dist/'))
        .pipe(filter('../server/dist/**/*.css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

But I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Autoprefixer> has no method 'on'
    at DestroyableTransform.Stream.pipe (stream.js:65:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/himmel/Sites/matt-mcdaniel.com/client/gulpfile.js:131:10)
```

I've included the necessary dependency, `autoprefixer-core`, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The error was thrown for an unknown reason due to inclusion of:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
```

After removing this, no error was thrown.

Additionally, including:

```
var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
        autoprefixPlugin = new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});
```

and

```
gulp.task('less', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app.less')
        .pipe(less({
            includePaths: ['less'],
            plugins: [autoprefixPlugin] //***//
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin({keepSpecialComments: 0}))
        .pipe(rename('app.full.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../server/dist/'))
        .pipe(filter('../server/dist/**/*.css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

was sufficient for my gulpfile to autoprefix on build, but did not autoprefix via `BrowserSync` during development.